# How to retrieve child data from parent entity in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

ParentEntity:

```
 public class Post {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
        private Integer id;

        private String title;

        private Integer image;

        private Integer views;

        @OneToOne
        private Author author;
    }
```

Child Entity

```
    public class Author{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    private String bio;
}
```

Now Post entity will be containing mapping of Author, i'm trying to get only Authors from post based on no.of views

i tired with below query, not sure how can i get

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new com.demo.v1.blog.dto.AuthorDto(p.author.id,a.name,p.author.bio,p.author.image,p.author.isDeleted,p.author.status,p.author.postsNum) FROM Post p order by views DESC")
Page<AuthorDto> getAuthorsByViews(Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT new com.demo.v1.blog.dto.AuthorDto(a.id,a.name,a.bio,a.image,a.isDeleted,a.status,a.postsNum) FROM Author a INNER JOIN Post p on a.id = p.author GROUP BY p.author order by p.views DESC")
Page<AuthorDto> getAuthorsByViews(Pageable pageable);
```

Join parent and child with common id and sort based on views